"Cannot find module" while reference image file path from Mongodb to React
I am trying to reference an image file path for a local image through Mongodb but I keep getting the error: "Cannot find module '../../itemImages/screwDriver1.jpg'". I have tried to fetch the image(item.image) in the following code:
{slider1Items
 .filter((item) => {
              if (item.topItem == true) {
                return item;
              }
            })
            .map((item, id) => (
              <div className='topItemsContainer' key={id}>
                <div>{item.itemName}</div>
                <img className='topItemImg' src={require(item.image)} />
                <div>{item.itemNumber}</div>
              </div>
            ))}

On mongodb, I have stored the value of the image as so:
image : "../../itemImages/screwDriver1.jpg"
I've tried inputting the file path into the source and it works:
src={require('../../itemImages/screwDriver1.jpg')}

but it doesn't work when I input :
src={require(item.image)} 

I have also tried without the require:
src={item.image}

but that just shows the placeholder instead of the image

Just to make sure I understand, the item within your mongo database has the path for your local image and that’s not being found properly?

@justnut Yes, the property in Mongodb has the value of the file path ('../../itemImages/screwDriver1.jpg'). This file path is only for the first item though. Each other item will obviously be different (e.g. ./../itemImages/screwDriver2.jpg, ./../itemImages/screwDriver3.jpg etc..)
